# Parsing HTML in python - lxml or BeautifulSoup? Which of these is better for what kinds of purposes?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, lxml

From what I can make out, the two main HTML parsing libraries in Python are lxml and BeautifulSoup. I've chosen BeautifulSoup for a project I'm working on, but I chose it for no particular reason other than finding the syntax a bit easier to learn and understand. But I see a lot of people seem to favour lxml and I've heard that lxml is faster.

So I'm wondering what are the advantages of one over the other? When would I want to use lxml and when would I be better off using BeautifulSoup? Are there any other libraries worth considering?

Comment: possible duplicate of [BeautifulSoup and lxml.html - what to prefer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967103/beautifulsoup-and-lxml-html-what-to-prefer)    I've written a [detailed answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19548832/1243926); reposted it here because the question is duplicate.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to close the other one. Now flagged the other one. I thought it didn't matter where to raise the flag, in the older one or in the newer one.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

<s>For starters, BeautifulSoup is no longer actively maintained, and [the author even recommends alternatives](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/3.1-problems.html) such as lxml.</s>

Quoting from the linked page:

> Version 3.1.0 of Beautiful Soup does
>   significantly worse on real-world HTML
>   than version 3.0.8 does. The most
>   common problems are handling 
>   tags incorrectly, "malformed start
>   tag" errors, and "bad end tag" errors.
>   This page explains what happened, how
>   the problem will be addressed, and
>   what you can do right now.
>
> This page was originally written in
>   March 2009. Since then, the 3.2 series
>   has been released, replacing the 3.1
>   series, and development of the 4.x
>   series has gotten underway. This page
>   will remain up for historical
>   purposes.
>
> **tl;dr**
>
> Use 3.2.0 instead.

Comment: +1 Didn't know about the decay of BeautifulSoup, which I rely upon and adore.

Comment: Well, lxml says it has good performance, while someone here said BeautifulSoup had really slow performance. It also seems to have decent API. http://codespeak.net/lxml/performance.html

Comment: IMHO this is misleading - careful reading of that page reveals that `lxml` is just an alternative for the problematic version 3.1.0, the problems of which were fixed in 3.2.0, and now there's even version 4 on the way released just 2 months ago - so the module is hardly "no longer actively maintained". *Please modify the answer*

Comment: Good to see BeautifulSoup getting maintained again. 3.2.0 was released in november 2010 --- almost a year after this answer.. :)

Comment: I'm doubting whether this should be the accepted answer of today. Everything here is pretty much useless information (other than nostalgic / historic purpose).

Comment: When I read this I thought that bs4 was dead. Was relieved to find "Use 3.2.0 instead."

Answer (score 27):

`Pyquery` provides the jQuery selector interface to Python (using lxml under the hood).

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery

It's really awesome, I don't use anything else anymore.

Comment: I've always wanted to try this lib out. Looks interesting.

Comment: This works better than bs4. I've had some problems with bs4 where the `diagnose` would not even work :(

Answer (score 20):

In summary, `lxml` is positioned as a lightning-fast production-quality html and xml parser that, by the way, also includes a `soupparser` module to fall back on BeautifulSoup's functionality. `BeautifulSoup` is a one-person project, designed to save you time to quickly extract data out of poorly-formed html or xml.

[lxml documentation](http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html) says that both parsers have advantages and disadvantages. For this reason, `lxml` provides a `soupparser` so you can switch back and forth. Quoting,

> BeautifulSoup uses a different parsing approach. It is not a real HTML
>   parser but uses regular expressions to dive through tag soup. It is
>   therefore more forgiving in some cases and less good in others. It is
>   not uncommon that lxml/libxml2 parses and fixes broken HTML better,
>   but BeautifulSoup has superiour support for encoding detection. **It
>   very much depends on the input which parser works better.**

In the end they are saying,

> The downside of using this parser is that it is **much slower** than
>   the HTML parser of  lxml. **So if performance matters, you might want
>   to consider using soupparser only as a fallback for certain cases.**

If I understand them correctly, it means that the soup parser is more robust --- it can deal with a "soup" of malformed tags by using regular expressions --- whereas `lxml` is more straightforward and just parses things and builds a tree as you would expect. I assume it also applies to `BeautifulSoup` itself, not just to the `soupparser` for `lxml`.

They also show how to benefit from `BeautifulSoup`'s encoding detection, while still parsing quickly with `lxml`:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import UnicodeDammit

>>> def decode_html(html_string):
...     converted = UnicodeDammit(html_string, isHTML=True)
...     if not converted.unicode:
...         raise UnicodeDecodeError(
...             "Failed to detect encoding, tried [%s]",
...             ', '.join(converted.triedEncodings))
...     # print converted.originalEncoding
...     return converted.unicode

>>> root = lxml.html.fromstring(decode_html(tag_soup))
```

(Same source: http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html).

In words of `BeautifulSoup`'s creator,

> That's it! Have fun! I wrote Beautiful Soup to save everybody time.
>   Once you get used to it, you should be able to wrangle data out of
>   poorly-designed websites in just a few minutes. Send me email if you
>   have any comments, run into problems, or want me to know about your
>   project that uses Beautiful Soup.
>
> ```
>  --Leonard
> ```

Quoted from the [Beautiful Soup documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Quick%20Start).

I hope this is now clear. The soup is a brilliant one-person project designed to save you time to extract data out of poorly-designed websites. The goal is to save you time right now, to get the job done, not necessarily to save you time in the long term, and definitely not to optimize the performance of your software.

Also, from the [lxml website](http://lxml.de/index.html),

> lxml has been downloaded from the Python Package Index more than two
>   million times and is also available directly in many package
>   distributions, e.g. for Linux or MacOS-X.

And, from [Why lxml?](http://lxml.de/intro.html),

> The C libraries libxml2 and libxslt have huge benefits:...
>   Standards-compliant...   Full-featured...  fast. fast! FAST! ...  lxml
>   is a new Python binding for libxml2 and libxslt...

Answer (score 11):

Don't use BeautifulSoup, use 
[lxml.soupparser](http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html) then you're sitting on top of the power of lxml and can use the good bits of BeautifulSoup which is to deal with really broken and crappy HTML.

Comment: I know this been posted very very long time ago but is this still active? Works as it did 2009? :D

Answer (score 5):

I've used lxml with great success for parsing HTML.  It seems to do a good job of handling "soupy" HTML, too.  I'd highly recommend it.

Here's a quick test I had lying around to try handling of some ugly HTML:

```
import unittest
from StringIO import StringIO
from lxml import etree

class TestLxmlStuff(unittest.TestCase):
    bad_html = """
        <html>
            <head><title>Test!</title></head>
            <body>
                <h1>Here's a heading
                <p>Here's some text
                <p>And some more text
                <b>Bold!</b></i>
                <table>
                   <tr>row
                   <tr><td>test1
                   <td>test2
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                   <td colspan=2>spanning two
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>"""

    def test_soup(self):
        """Test lxml's parsing of really bad HTML"""
        parser = etree.HTMLParser()
        tree = etree.parse(StringIO(self.bad_html), parser)
        self.assertEqual(len(tree.xpath('//tr')), 3)
        self.assertEqual(len(tree.xpath('//td')), 3)
        self.assertEqual(len(tree.xpath('//i')), 0)
        #print(etree.tostring(tree.getroot(), pretty_print=False, method="html"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

For sure i would use EHP. It is faster than lxml, much more elegant and simpler to use.

Check out. https://github.com/iogf/ehp

```
<body ><em > foo  <font color="red" ></font></em></body>


from ehp import *

data = '''<html> <body> <em> Hello world. </em> </body> </html>'''

html = Html()
dom = html.feed(data)

for ind in dom.find('em'):
    print ind.text()
```

Output:

```
Hello world.
```

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat outdated speed comparison can be found [here](http://blog.ianbicking.org/2008/03/30/python-html-parser-performance/), which clearly recommends lxml, as the speed differences seem drastic.