# Python - Getting all images from an html file

Tags: python, image, urllib

Can someone help me parse a html file to get the links for all the images in the file in python?

Preferably with out a 3rd party module...

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). I know you said *without* a 3rd party module. However, this is an ideal tool for parsing HTML.

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
page = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.url.com"))
page.findAll('img')
```

Comment: OK. Seems like this will help it out alot so I'll check it out. Thanks!

Comment: I think Russell missed `BeautifulSoup(page)`

Answer (score 11):

only using PSL

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
class MyParse(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag=="img":
            print(dict(attrs)["src"])

h=MyParse()
page=open("index.html").read()
h.feed(page)
```

Comment: You can augment this with urllib to open a web page and download the images.

Comment: For me this only works with "from HTMLParser import HTMLParser"

Answer (score 2):

It's generally accepted that lxml is faster than Beautiful Soup [(ref)](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:4IjHWqUmjEAJ:blog.dispatched.ch/2010/08/16/beautifulsoup-vs-lxml-performance/+beautifulsoup+performance&cd=3&ct=clnk). Its tutorial can be found here: [(link)](http://codespeak.net/lxml/tutorial.html)
You may also take a look at [this old stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922032/parsing-html-in-python-lxml-or-beautifulsoup-which-of-these-is-better-for-what).