# How to scrape the height and width of a table using Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<table id="t_id" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" height="700" width="600" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr><td> ..test... </td></tr>
<tr><td> ..test... </td></tr>
<tr><td> ..test... </td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

People tend to prefer lxml these days over BeautifulSoup. See how easy this is:

```
from lxml import etree
data = """<table id="t_id" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" height="700" width="600" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr><td> ..test... </td></tr>
<tr><td> ..test... </td></tr>
<tr><td> ..test... </td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
"""
tree = etree.fromstring(data)
table_element = tree.xpath("/table")[0] # because it returns a list of table elements
print table_element.attrib['height'] + " and " + table_element.attrib['width']
```

Comment: Why do people prefer lxml? Performance reasons? Because the BeautifulSoup solution is shorter and looks more pythonic IMHO.

Comment: I'm a fan of BeautifulSoup too, but it does look like it's going the way of the dodo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922032/parsing-html-in-python-lxml-or-beautifulsoup-which-of-these-is-better-for-what/1922064#1922064

Comment: You can still use beautiful soup without problems if you're not building anything "critical". However, there are a lot of changes in the latest (3.1.0) version. If you want to use BS, I would recommend to use the 3.0.8 one.

Answer (score 1):

If this is your whole HTML, then this will suffice:

```
import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup("...your HTML...")
print soup.table['width'], soup.table['height']
# prints: 600 700
```

If you need to search for the table first, it's not much more complicated, either:

```
table = soup.find('table', id='t_id')
print table['width'], table['height']
```