# Grab url from href and text

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have tried using regex but read around and got directed to beautiful soup...

I've kinda figured out how to get urls in html tags with soup, but how would I grab urls from both html tags (href=*) and the body text of the page?

Also for grabbing the ones in tags, how do I specify that I only want urls starting with http://, https://... ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First look at [parsing-html-in-python-lxml-or-beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922032/parsing-html-in-python-lxml-or-beautifulsoup-which-of-these-is-better-for-wha). I read it and never looked at the soup. I guess because I find lxml so easy. I am sure there are different ways to do what you asked, perhaps there are easier ones. But I'll show what I use.

In lxml you can use [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) it's like using regex for XML/HTML. This code below will find all "a" tags that have "http" attribute and print all links that start with http. This should help you get started on your parsing.

```
from lxml.html import etree

tree = etree.parse("my.html", etree.HTMLParser())
root = tree.getroot()
links = root.findall('*//a[@href]')
foreach link in links:
    if link.get("http").startswith("http"):
        print link.get("http")
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful head start! I'll try to work out all the other bits I'm going for and come back with what I get.