# What's the relationship between 'BeautifulSoup' and 'lxml'?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, lxml

In `lxml`'s [doc](http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html), it says:

> lxml can interface to the parsing capabilities of BeautifulSoup through the lxml.html.soupparser module. It provides three main functions: fromstring() and parse() to parse a string or file using BeautifulSoup into an lxml.html document, and convert_tree() to convert an existing BeautifulSoup tree into a list of top-level Elements.

Meanwhile, `BS`' can also use `lxml` as the parser.[[ref]](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)

> Beautiful Soup supports the HTML parser included in Python’s standard library, but it also supports a number of third-party Python parsers. One is the lxml parser.

`BS` also **suggests** to use `lxml` as the parser for speed.

So what if `lxml` uses `BS` for parsing when `BS`'s parser is `lxml`  conversely?

I have been scratching my head over understanding their relationship. Help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing HTML in python - lxml or BeautifulSoup? Which of these is better for what kinds of purposes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922032/parsing-html-in-python-lxml-or-beautifulsoup-which-of-these-is-better-for-wha)

Comment: I upvoted your question as I thought it was a good one. Then I noticed the top-listed Related question and followed the link. I thought the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/19549530/1640661 was excellent and helps clarify the relationship between the functionality of these two libraries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing should be confusing about `BS` parser and `lxml.html` parser. `BS` has an HTML parser, and `lxml` has its own HTML parser.

`BS` documentation you quoted simply says that you can parse HTML into `BS` soup object using `lxml` parser or other possible third-party parsers, as alternative to using the default `BS` parser :

```
BeautifulSoup(markup, "lxml")
```

Similarly, the `lxml` documentation says that you can parse HTML into `lxml` tree object using `BS` parser, as alternative to using the default `lxml.html` parser :

```
root = lxml.html.soupparser.fromstring(tag_soup)
```