# Extract an unusual XML tag with BS4 and Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, tags

Couldn't find the answer anywhere.
I have an XML:

```
<channel>
    <title>xxx</title>
    <description>aaa</description>
    <item>
        <title>theTitle</title>
        <link/>link
        </item>
        <title>theTitle2</title>
        <link/>link
        </item>
```

And I need to extract all the links from that file.

I iterate:

```
for link in soup.channel.findAll('item'):
    links = link.link
    linkdict.append(links)
```

But the output is:

```
[<link/>, <link/>, <link/>]
```

How can I parse this xml with/without using regex. I want the code to be as simple as it could be.

---

### UPDATE

I've found the way to do it in one line of code:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(output, features='xml')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install  Xml using this - `pip install lxml`
And then you can easily parse using

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup(xmlString,"lxml")
```

Comment: Thank you, I did that. XML in the question was received by `soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(output, 'lxml')`.  @user2420450

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have `lxml` installed, you can use it *directly* instead of via `BeautifulSoup`. In `lxml` tree model, the `link` texts will be available as *tail* of the corresponding `<link/>` elements :

```
from lxml import etree

raw = '''<channel> 
  <title>xxx</title>  
  <description>aaa</description>  
  <item> 
    <title>theTitle</title>  
    <link/>link
  </item>  
  <item> 
    <title>theTitle2</title>  
    <link/>link
  </item> 
</channel>'''

root = etree.fromstring(raw)
for link in root.xpath('//item/link'):
    print link.tail.strip()
```

**output :**

```
link
link
```

XPath expression `//item/link` means *find `item` element, anywhere in current document, and return corresponding child element `link`*. It is also worth mentioning that `lxml` is known to be faster than BS4 in most case.

<sub>References :</sub>
<sub>1) [BeautifulSoup 4 Benchmark](https://www.crummy.com/2012/01/22/0)</sub>
<sub>2) [Parsing HTML in python - lxml or BeautifulSoup? Which of these is better for what kinds of purposes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19549530/2998271)</sub>

Comment: Thank you, it worked with a bit of editing. But when I did it, I've found the way to do it with bs4 only and in one line. Updated my own question.